# Ignore Errors on running PS Script

Tags: powershell, file, search, access-denied

I have a script that I want to use to search for files on a PC:

```
$Extensions = @(".bat")

Foreach ( $Extension in $Extensions )
{
   [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("C:\Users\","*$Extension","AllDirectories")
}
```

The error I get is

> An error occurred while enumerating through a collection: Access to
>   the path [...] is denied.

I tried adding catch[Exception]

```
$Extensions = @(".bat")
Foreach ( $Extension in $Extensions )
{{  [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles("C:\Users\","*$Extension","AllDirectories")
catch [Exception]
}
}
```

And well, no more error message but it does not return the list of items I'm looking for.

I want to use this method and not the

> Get-ChildItems

because I eventually want to run this against a lot of Remote Computers and Get-Childitem is too slow.

Comment: So from the error message, you are not having permission for the path. Why dont you try running that in elevated mode and see if it works. Else change the folder permissions in ACL ; that should do the trick for you.

Comment: one reason for NOT using that method is that it simply stops when it triggers an error. there is no error handling built into it  AT ALL. is just _stops_. if you want to use that faster-but-very-finicky method, you will have to write your own error handling. i recommend looking as how dotnet & c# do it - i cannot find anything in published powershell code ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've seen them online but my knowledge of C# is 0, and they had full scripts, don't know which snippets I specifically need - even this small script is compiled from little bits and pieces I found online.

Comment: if your current skill level is not up for it ... _do not do it_. [*grin*] mine is certainly not up the the level needed. you may be able to use robocopy if you don't mind parsing the log it produces. the log is rather simple, so it is not too difficult to parse. ///// another idea  - run the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet on the target systems, not across the network. take a look at `Invoke-Command`. it accepts a list of systems and a scriptblock to run on them. the results are sent back to the calling system.

Comment: You have put in a `catch` bot forgot the `try`. [About Try Catch Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-6). And yes, if you do not have permission to enter the folders in C:\Users you will not get the desired results.